# Dynamically assign variable type in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, polymorphism

I would like to create an algorithm that can use priority_queue or a regular queue depending on the case. So the same variable should be assigned to queue or priority queue, but the rest of the code would be the same. In Java it is possible because of inheritance

```
Queue<Customer> customerPriorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<>(capacity, idComparator);
```

Is something like this available in C++?

Comment: Yes, C++ has inheritance.

Comment: C++ standard containers aren't polymorphic for performance reasons. You shouldn't program C++ in Java style. If you definitely want to do it, you'll have to roll your own polymorphic classes.

Comment: Is the decision made in compile-time or run-time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to make your class templated on the type of container that you are going to use, e.g:

```
template < typename Queue >
class Test
{
    Queue queue;
public:
    void push( int i )
    {
        queue.push( i );
    }
};
```

If you want a fully Java style polymorphic container base class:

```
template < typename T >
class Queue
{
public:
   virtual void push( const T& t ) = 0;    
};

template < typename Q >
class QueueImpl : public Queue< typename Q::value_type >
{
public:
   typedef typename Q::value_type value_type;

   virtual void push( const value_type& t ) override
   {
       q.push( t );
   }

private:
   Q q;
};

std::unique_ptr< Queue< int > > queue = std::make_unique< QueueImpl< std::queue< int > > >();
queue->push( 1 );
```